# zsh theme for full path + display git changes

Tags: git, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I'm looking for theme to display a full path + git (branch name + uncommitted changes + added files).
Didn't find any. 
something like this:

```
/full/path/to/repo (master *+)
```

would love a recommendation of one / a tip of how to edit an existing one (I am currently using Godzilla).

Comment: Zsh itself does not have themes. Perhaps you meant `oh-my-zsh`? Correctly tagging the question would help bringing the right people to look at your question.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Run `man zshmisc` and search for the  `SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES` section.
This documents escapes which can be used to theme your prompt.

To get the full path path of your current working directory use `%d`.

I'm assuming you're using oh-my-zsh. In order to accomplish what you want, you can create a modified version of the Godzilla theme and replace the `%c` (which just shows the current folder) with `%d` in the `PROMPT`.

See here:
https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/c78277fd8bda5fec87504469afdf121355876006/themes/gozilla.zsh-theme#L1

Comment: Is there a way to make "/Users/myuser/Desktop" become "~/Desktop" when using %d instead of %c? Thankss!

Comment: You can use `%~` (instead of `%d`) to show `~/Desktop/path/` instead of `/Users/myuser/Desktop/path/`. http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html

Answer (score 150):

Creating a copy of original theme file is the recommended way of tweaking original theme files. [Oh-my-zsh docs](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Customization#overriding-and-adding-themes)

Check your existing theme:

```bash
$ echo $ZSH_THEME
robbyrussell
```

Create a copy of original theme file in your `$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes` directory:

```bash
cp $ZSH/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme $ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/
```

Edit your custom copy of theme file

```bash
vim $ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme
```

Which looks like this:

```bash
PROMPT+=' %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)'
#                       ^ replace c with ~
```

Then source theme again:

```bash
exec zsh
```

It will now show the path relative to your home directory (`~`). For example:

```bash
# BEFORE
➜  sqlboiler git:(master)
# AFTER
➜  ~/open-source/sqlboiler git:(master)
```

Comment: Instead of changing the default theme file, I would recommend copying the `PROMT=` lines to the end of `~/.zshrc` before customizing them

Comment: good point, I was satisfied with `cp ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme.orig`

Comment: This didn't work for me at all. https://i.imgur.com/3otsfsa.png

Comment: If your theme is not `robbyrussell` you will need to edit different theme file. You can find your current active theme in `~/.zshrc` file under `ZSH_THEME` variable

Comment: copy command,  copy the file from `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussel.zsh-themes`  to `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/robbyrussel.zsh-theme` 
and we edit this file then how does `exec command` read from */custom/themse* location but not from */themes* location ?

Answer (score 17):

Besides other answers,

If you also want to add the `username` and/or `hostname`, add the three lines below in the end of `~/.zshrc` to overwrite the PROMPT:

```sh
PROMPT="%{$fg_bold[white]%}%n %{$fg[blue]%}@ %{$fg_bold[yellow]%}%m"

PROMPT+=" %(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ )"

PROMPT+=' %{$fg[cyan]%}%d%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)'
```

Explanation:

`%n` is the username

`%m` is the hostname

`%d` is the directory (you can replace it with `%~`)

Note: Space between `username` and `hostname` is added in the example above is for clarity, you can remove them if you want.

Answer (score 7):

Locate your current theme in `~/.zshrc` file defined under variable named `ZSH_THEME`. You are supposed to edit the file according to the theme(current zsh theme) defined here. Default one is `robbyrussell`.

For default theme edit this file: `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme` Find `PROMPT` variable definition in file(Note: You can find multiple variable declaration with concatenation, find the one that matches structure mentioned below). It should have something like below:

`PROMPT+='%{$fg[blue]%}%~%{$reset_color%}`

Modify the middle part of `PROMPT` variable as your preference from following to change prompt path. Example how path would look like for each setting is shown below:

1. `%~%` -> shows: `~/example_dir/temp/hello_world`
2. `%d%` -> shows: `/User/ydave/Desktop/example_dir/temp/hello_world`
3. `%2d` -> shows: `temp/hello_world`
4. `%3d` -> shows: `example_dir/temp/hello_world`
5. `%c%` -> shows: `hello_world`